# Dataflow unable to parse template file with custom template

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a simple pipeline in dataflow

```
import apache_beam as beam


options = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()

gcloud_options = options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions)
gcloud_options.job_name = 'dataflow-tutorial1'
gcloud_options.project = 'xxxx'
gcloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://xxxx/staging'
gcloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://xxxx/temp'
gcloud_options.service_account_email = 'dataflow@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com'


worker_options = options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.WorkerOptions)
worker_options.disk_size_gb = 20
worker_options.max_num_workers = 2


options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'


p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

(p1 | 'Hello World' >> beam.Create(['Hello World']))

p1.run()
```

When I create the job from the dataflow UI and try to run it, I keep getting

```
Unable to parse template file 'gs://dataflow-sm/pipeline-files/read-write-to-gsc-file.py'.
```

If I run it from terminal I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Unable to parse template file 'gs://dataflow-sm/pipeline-files/read-write-to-gsc-file.py'.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: "Unexpected end of stream : expected '{'"
    subject: 0:0
    type: JSON
```

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a step: converting your Python code to a JSON template. Instructions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates). For Python, in particular:

```py
python read-write-to-gsc-file.py \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  ...
  --template_location gs://dataflow-sm/pipeline-files/read-write-to-gsc-file
```

The template will be staged at the GCS path specified with `--template_location`. See the Google-provided [word count template](https://storage.cloud.google.com/dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count) as an example.

Then you can [execute](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#using-gcloud) the template providing `--gcs-location`:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run [JOB_NAME] \
        --gcs-location gs://dataflow-sm/pipeline-files/read-write-to-gsc-file
```

Comment: For some reason the template is not written to the `template_location`. When I run the first command, the pipeline is executed (weird) but the template is never generated. What could be the cause? I implemented the pipeline in Jupyter Notebooks and then exported it as an executable script.