# Google Dataflow - Unable to parse template file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I have written a python script using apache beam and I'm now trying to execute it using Google Dataflow. However, when I attempt to create the job, I get the following error:

```
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
    "violations": [
      {
        "type": "JSON",
        "subject": "0:0",
        "description": "Unexpected end of stream : expected '{'"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I understand that I have to transform my python code into JSON somehow, but I haven't found very clear documentation about exactly how that is done. I've tried running the command as described in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-a-classic-template):

```
  python -m examples.mymodule \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project PROJECT_ID \
    --staging_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME \
    --region REGION
```

both locally and in the google cloud shell but I get this error:
`error: argument --runner: expected one argument`, despite having run `pip install apache-beam[gcp]`.

I have already seen this question [Dataflow unable to parse template file with custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771475/dataflow-unable-to-parse-template-file-with-custom-template) but I wasn't able to get it working with the provided answer.

Thank you for reading and thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible, can you please add your code here?

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a comment, though I am not able to comment yet.

I use the same command for staging the template, so I don't think that's the issue. My guess is your pipeline code.
Are you using `pipeline.run()` as described in the linked stackoverflow post? If so, try this instead:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
   (
       p 
       | 'Hello World' >> beam.Create(['Hello World'])
       | 'Print Hello World' >> beam.Map(print)
   )
```